# Codifying in a variant-text based machlokes

Tags: halacha, sources-mekorot, halacha-theory, posek-psak-decisor-ruling, nuschaot

The בית חדש in [O.C. 168](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=14265&st=&pgnum=288) writes the following:

> אלא דלהלכה ודאי במידי דתליא
>    בגירסאות אזלינן לחומרא הכי והכי

In something which is dependent on variant texts we are stringent in both directions.

I have never seen this rule before, and מלתא דלא רמיא עליה דאינש לאו אדעתיה (that which you aren't looking for you don't notice) but I have the sense that in my experience learning halacha this rule is not generally followed.

Do any other poskim  follow this rule, and is it sourced somewhere?